# Ошибка сравнения в процедуре MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

Локально установлен MySQL 8.
В Laravel выполнена миграция.

Код миграции

```
Schema::create('tickets_dol', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('ticket', 50)->index();
        $table->string('userAdded', 50)->index();
        $table->string('status', 64)->index();
        $table->dateTime('statusDate');
        $table->string('userAddedDOL', 50)->nullable();
    });
```

В миграции создается процедура

```
$procedure = "
        create
            definer = dev@`%` procedure DOL_GetTicketsByTN(IN xTN varchar(50), IN xStatus varchar(64)) comment 'Список тикетов по табельному номеру и статусу'
        BEGIN
            select * from tickets_dol where userAdded = xTN and status = xStatus;
        END;
    ";

    DB::unprepared("DROP procedure IF EXISTS DOL_GetTicketsByTN");
    DB::unprepared($procedure);
```

Вывод show create table tickets_dol;

```
    CREATE TABLE `tickets_dol` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticket` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `userAdded` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `statusDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `userAddedDOL` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tickets_dol_ticket_index` (`ticket`),
  KEY `tickets_dol_useradded_index` (`userAdded`),
  KEY `tickets_dol_status_index` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

При вызове процедуры

call DOL_GetTicketsByTN('0000000351', 'New');

Получаю ошибку

[HY000][1267] Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%';

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если таблицу создать не из миграции, а просто запросом без указания COLLATE, то процедура выполняется.

Конфиг MySQL

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему ругается процедура при создании таблицы через миграции и как это исправить?
Или как делать миграции чтобы COLLATE не использовать при создании таблицы?

Comment: [offtop] *`where ... status = status`* - это могуче... [/offtop]

Comment: @akina а что смущает? поле и имя переменной, разве они не могут совпадать по наименованию?

Comment: Меня ничего не смущает. Просто я не вижу смысла сравнивать переменную с собой - есть более штатный способ проверки на NULL. А чтобы использовать поле, одноимённое с переменной - указание алиаса таблицы ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО. Переменная маскирует поле. Т.е. должно быть ```where ... tickets_dol.status = status``` - тогда будет сравнение поля и переменной.